# How can I upload and password protect Javadocs in Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, html, directory, authentication

I'm trying to host our software's Javadocs online behind a paywall. We tried to render the docs in Wordpress, which failed (obviously). My theory is that we could upload a folder directly to our root in WordPress (which works fine when we don't have a login, i.e., on our main site), but I don't know if that would be possible using our login plugin. Ultimately, I need a solution that would allow me to bulk upload (without altering in any way) 300+ HTML Javadocs behind a paywall. Is this possible in WordPress or do I need to create a custom solution?

Our site currently uses WPForo (for our forum) and Restrict Content Pro to manage access.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your server to protect a directory of your choice and allow access only to the user running apache/nginx/etc. You would have to write something to verify the user's credentials and then deliver the file or redirect to the proper url.

It's not difficult, but I don't know of a solution that would support this.